# use babel source instead of babel packages (@babel/*)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, vue3-sfc-loader

I would like to embed babel in my project using source version (`github.com/babel`) instead of packaged version (npm `@babel/*`) in order to benefits of a better (webpack) tree-shaking (`@babel/*` is cjs whereas `github.com/babel` is mjs/ts/flow).

I use 3rd-party libraries that require `node_modules/@babel/*` and I would like to configure TypeScript to make it use `node_modules/babel/packages/babel-*/src` instead.

I am aware that there is no module alias in TypeScript.

I tried with `compilerOptions.paths` with no success :

```
    paths: {
        '@babel/code-frame': ['babel/packages/babel-code-frame/src'],
        '@babel/...': ['babel/packages/babel-.../src'],
        ...
    }
```

Is there a trick to make any require to `@babel/*` to point to `babel/packages/babel-*/src` ?

**note:** in my webpack configuration file, I use:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@babel/code-frame': 'babel/backages/babel-code-frame/src',
```

and I'm looking for the equivalent for typescript.

Related context: https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader/issues/7

*(feel free to ask me more details if necessary)*

**Edit:**
I think the resolution of this question is doomed to failure since (AFAIK) TypeScript cannot import [flow](https://flow.org/) files. My only option is to wait the resolution of [Migrate Babel from Flow to TypeScript](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/11578) PR.

Comment: You have the right idea: align Webpack alias with TS paths. You just need to fix your tsconfig.json paths so they actually point at something. They need to be relative to the baseUrl so they need to be prefixed with node_modules

Comment: I would just symlink the folder.

Comment: Typescript is build-time only. The answer depends on what runtime you use. Webpack, node, ts-node?

Comment: Sorry, I see you are using Webpack. For typescript, you need to give relative file path like `./node_modules/babel/packages...`. The path is relative to `baseUrl` parameter in `tsconfig.json`.